# How do I force the use of the desktop menu when the grid is fluid?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7 and Omega 3. The front page of my website needs an image that covers only the top half of the page, and it needs to expand to full width regardless of the browser size.  I found that I can do this by creating a delta for the home page. When the grid is set to fluid it will allow the image to use the entire wrapper for the branding area. However, setting the grid to fluid causes using the mobile menu instead of desktop menu.

How can I either stretch the image full width in 960 OR use the fluid grid and have the desktop menu appear rather than the mobile menu?

[image: 960 grid, uses correct (desktop) menu, but not filling the wrapper]
[image: fluid grid, but mobile menu used on desktop, however image fills wrapper as it should]

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use "`vh or vw`" if you need manipulation with browser size.
2. Try to use "`background-size: 100%;`" on `100%` pass needed value.
3. On drupal if you are using module for output different menus and using different templates double check your conditions.
4. Try to check your `@media` query's in css on width size for this menu.